# Net Core 3.1 OData returns error 500 when using both $filter and $select and output is xml

Tags: sql, xml, .net-core, odata

I'm currently developing an OData API in .Net Core 3.1 which fetches data from SQL server. Using postman, I'm sending GET requests to the API with Accept headers text/xml and application/json.

With this url: <http://localhost:8008/odata/Contact?$filter=No_ eq 'T20-1234567'&$select=No_> and an  application/json Accept-Header (or No Accept-Header) the response is

[json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHRWY.png)

But with  Accept-Header application/xml or text/xml:

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder+SelectSome`1[Models.Contact]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.Contact]'.

The strange thing is that when the $select part is removed from the url, the request is correctly handled by the application (200).

My controller action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute(nameof(Contact))]
    public IQueryable<Contact> GetContact()
    {
        return _context.Contact;
    }
```

Has anyone seen this type of behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, here's a possible workaround:

```
    services
        .AddMvc(config =>
            {
                ...
                config.OutputFormatters.Add(new CustomXmlOutputFormatter());
                config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            });
```

```
public class CustomXmlOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
    {
        public CustomXmlOutputFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml"));

            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
        }

        protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
        {
            if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            if (selectedEncoding == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selectedEncoding));

            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { item = context.Object });

            var xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "root");

            var buffer = new StringBuilder(xml.ToString());

            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(buffer.ToString());
        }
    }
```